# Hidden div in a li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu icon. When I click on the search icon, a hidden input form appears for the search. The problem is that when I click on the icon the form slides fast on the right but the icon image goes down and is not fixed.

This is the function I have created in the workers theme's function.php:

```html
<ul class="icone">
    <li><div class="search-lens"><?php get_search_form(); ?></div><a class="search-click" href="#"><img src="image.png"></a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the javascript function:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery(".search-click").click(function(){
        jQuery(".search-lens").toggle('fast');
    });
```

And this is the custom css code:

```css
.icone{
    width:15%;
    margin:10px auto;
    position:relative;
}
.icone li{
    width:45px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    list-style:none;
}

form.search-form{
    float:left;       
}

div.search-lens {
    display:none;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

[image]
[image]

So how to avoid the icon sliding down when I click on it?

Comment: Could you please share the link of your website to check the console in problematic situation?

Comment: It seems that not only that icon is moving but also the rest of the content.
It has something to do with the "width" of the container(div?) of those elements together.

Comment: The website is www.alesitiprova.it

Answer (score 0):

Set your .search-lens to 'float: right;' you may also need to change the width to a smaller value.

Comment: I have set it to float right, but the behavior is the same, with the icon that fall down

Comment: I think you need to shrink the size of div.search-lens. Take out or reduce the margin-left attribute and start manually setting a width. Start with something small and see if that fixes the icon issue, If so increase the width to you find that sweet spot.

Comment: Seeing the css and html for the icons them selves would also be helpful. You may need to adjust their attributes as well.

Also take out the width attributes for .icone and .icone li.

Comment: Yes the problem was the icon li width.. and the icon li img set to 100%. Thank you very much for your suggestions

Comment: My pleasure. If you could mark the answer correct I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It would be my pleasure to mark your answer as correct, but i don't know how to do it

Comment: Hi Thanks. I'm actually pretty new to this myself and haven't asked a question yet so I'm not sure either. I imagine it's somewhere in your account dashboard listed with your questions? Don't sweat it, though. I'm glad I could help.